# Kausale Präpositionen "aus" + "wegen"

Tags: preposition, dative, genitive

> Sie haben (1) __________ vielen Gründen nur wenige Leute eingeladen
> und (2) __________ Terminproblemen in den Sommerferien haben auch noch
> einige Gäste abgesagt.

In (1) habe ich *aus* eingesetzt und wollte in (2) *wegen* einsetzen, aber die Endung *-n* in Dativ Plural verwirrt mich. In den Lösungen steht tatsächlich *wegen Terminproblemen* und die Google-Suche nach "wegen Terminproblemen" ergab viele Treffer mit Satzbeispielen. Könntet Ihr mir bitte erklären, warum es nicht *wegen Terminprobleme* (Sg. n. *Problem* Pl. *die Probleme*; Gen. Pl. *der Probleme*; die Präposition *wegen* verlangt Genitiv) heißt und warum *-n* angehängt wird? Oder handelt es sich hier überhaupt nicht um Genitiv?

Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bei den Genitivpräpositionen steht manchmal der Dativ statt des Genitivs.

- wegen/trotz des Problems — richtig
- wegen/trotz dem Problem — umgangssprachlich, ansonsten falsch
- wegen/trotz der Probleme — richtig
- wegen/trotz den Problemen — umgangssprachlich, ansonsten falsch
- wegen/trotz Probleme — falsch (!)
- wegen/trotz Problemen — richtig (!)
- wegen/trotz ständiger Probleme — richtig (Ja, wirklich!)
- wegen/trotz ständigen Problemen — richtig (!)

Das ist leider so. Es steckt auch keine tiefere Logik dahinter. Es machen sich auch die wenigsten Muttersprachler Gedanken darüber, sonst hätte man dir diese Trickfrage ja gar nicht erst gestellt.

Answer (score 1):

Standardsprachlich ist zunächst mal der Genitiv richtig, allerdings wird vor allem in der Umgangssprache der Dativ mehr und mehr üblich. Besonders in Fällen, in denen der Genitiv nicht gut erkennbar wäre, wird der Dativ verwendet. Das betrifft insbesondere Fälle, in denen das Nomen ohne einen Artikel oder ein Adjektiv steht.

> Wegen eines Terminproblems haben einige Gäste abgesagt.

> Wegen starker Regenfälle musste die Straße gesperrt werden.

Weil ein Artikel ("eines"), beziehungsweise ein Adjektiv ("starker") dabei steht, ist der Genitiv gut erkennbar. Man kann sich gewissermaßen an die Regel halten.

> Wegen Terminproblemen haben einige Gäste abgesagt.

Hier ist kein Artikel und kein Adjektiv dabei, deshalb wird hier der Dativ verwendet.

Weitere Informationen zu dieser Frage gibt es beispielsweise auf [DW Deutsch Lernen](https://learngerman.dw.com/de/kausale-pr%C3%A4positionen-wegen/l-38489408/gr-39127564#), [deutschlernerblog.de](https://deutschlernerblog.de/wegen-dem-oder-wegen-des-wegen-dativ-oder-genitiv/) oder bei der [GfdS](https://gfds.de/wegen-fall-nach/).

Comment: Wenn jemand *wegen Terminprobleme* schriebe, würde man von einem Fehler ausgehen. Daran zeigt sich, dass der Dativ hier nichts mit Umgangssprache zu tun hat, sondern die standardsprachliche Form ist.

Comment: Alle drei in der Antwort angegeben Links sagen auch, dass die Dativform hier, also beim beim Gebrauch ohne Artikel im Plural, die standardsprachliche (also richtige) Form ist. Ich verstehe das nicht so, dass die Genitiv-Form auch richtig ist.

Comment: Der Satz "ist grammatikalisch korrekt, aber mittlerweile unüblich." ist leider ganz einfach falsch. Das war so noch nie richtiges Deutsch, da der Genitiv in deinem Beispiel nicht markiert.

Comment: *Wegen die Terminprobleme? Ich dachte das haben wir besprochen und du hättest dir drum jekümmert!*

Comment: Ich hatte die Quellen, die ich gefunden (und meistenteils verlinkt) hatte, eigentlich so verstanden, dass ursprünglich der Genitiv in allen Fällen formal korrekt war. Im Lauf der Zeit begann sich "wegen" mit Dativ zu verbreiten. In bestimmten Fällen, nämlich wenn der Genitiv nicht klar erkennbar ist, wurde der Dativ dann schließlich (zusätzlich zum Genitiv?) als formal korrekt akzeptiert. Aber ich will nicht ausschließen, dass ich das falsch verstanden habe.